# Database Formatting for Album Tracks

Tags: mysql, database-design

- I would like to store album's
  track names in a single field in a
  database.
- The number of tracks are arbitrary
  for each album.
- Each album is one record in the table.
- Each track must be linked to a specific URL which also should be stored in the database somewhere.

Is it possible to do this by storing them in a single field, or is a relational table for the track names/urls the only way to go?

Comment: Why do you want it in a single field? (And when you say "field" do you mean "row" or "column"?)

Comment: field = colummn.  i want it in a single field because modifying the existing databse i'm working with to function with the existing application is going to be a pain.  however, adding them in a single field will simplify everything greatly.

Comment: Surely adding new table(s) for Track/Album-track relationship would be simplier, as the existing schema wouldn't need to change?

Comment: i wish this application was one that was easy to modify.

Comment: thanks for all the answers, with best-practices, all good approaches.

Comment: Storing multiple items (track names) in any one field of a database row means that your schema is inherently denormalized.  In fact it's not even in first normal form.

It's *possible* to create tables in MySQL (or any other SQL DBMS) which are not normalized.  You can always create a CHAR or VARCHAR or even a BLOB column into which you encode your own lists (separated by commas, colons, tabs, or whatever you like).

However before you commit your project design to such a schema you should read about normalization and the sorts of anomalies it's intended to avoid.  (see below)

Comment: I already know about all that.  Thanks though, they are VERY important for those who don't.  Unfortunately, when it comes to modifying existing systems, and you're only being paid for 1 hours worth of work, you wouldn't go through the trouble of fixing everything would you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's entirely possible, you could store the field as comma-separated or XML data for example.

Whether it's *sensible* is another question - if you ever want to query how many albums have more than 10 tracks for example you aren't going to be able to write an SQL query for that and you'll have to resort to pulling the data back into your application and dissecting it there which is not ideal.

Another option is to store the data in a separate "tracks" table (i.e. normalised), but also provide a view on those tables that gives the data as a single field in a denormalised manner.  Then you get the benefit of properly structured data and the ability to query the data as a single field from the view.

Comment: ah ha!  absolutely.  delimit the data in the field and then split it by the delimiter in the application?  why didn't i think of that.

Comment: although the other answers gave me the 'correct' way to do this...this one answered my question directly. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
Table: Album
ID/PK (your choice of primary key philosophy)
AlbumName

Table: Track
ID/PK (optional, could make AlbumFK, TrackNumber the primary key)
AlbumFK REFERENCES (Album.PK)
TrackNumber
TrackName
TrackURL
```

Answer (score 1):

Conventional approach would be to have one table with a row for each track (with any meta data). Have another table for each Album, and a third table that records the association for which tracks are on which album(s) and in which order.

Comment: yes, i agree...but as my question states, I was looking to see if there was another way to get them into one field.

Answer (score 1):

Use two tables, one for albums, and one for tracks.

```
Album
-----
Id
Name
Artist
etc...



Track
-----
Id
AlbumId(Foreign Key to Album Table)
Name
URL
```

You could also augment this with a third table that joined the trackId and AlbumId fields (so don't have the AlbumId in the Track table). The advantage of this second approach would be that it would allow you to reuse a recording when it appeared on many albums (such as compilations).

Comment: as my question states, I was looking to see if there was another way to get them into one field.

Comment: ..or a step further if you ever want to extend to include info like songwriter/composer which would be common for a greatest hits album, and the original album...

Comment: @Sev If you want to store everything in a single column, you can just use a simple XML schema.

Comment: I thought your original question asked for track "names" in a single column, not all track info, and didn't mention relational tables at all.

Comment: +1 Roland - I modified my answer to accommodate your suggestion

Comment: @paddyslacker: thanks for the nice explanation of the use of the third table.

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia article on [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_forms) makes a reasonable effort to explain the purpose of normalization ... and the sorts of anomalies that the normalization rules are intended to prevent.

Comment: i already know this.  plus this has nothing to do with my question. thanks though.